# hex2bin in data frame

Tags: r

I'm new to R and excited about all the possibilities of data management and presentation.
Actually I have a problem and did not find any solution:

I have built a data frame with:

```
require(BMS)
n = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
s = c("55aa55aa", "aa55aa55", "12345678", "9ABCDEF0", "55aa55aa", "aa55aa55", "12345678", "9ABCDEF0")
df = data.frame(n, s)
df$s <- as.character(df$s)
df
#   n        s
# 1 1 55aa55aa
# 2 2 aa55aa55
# 3 3 12345678
# 4 4 9ABCDEF0
# 5 5 55aa55aa
# 6 6 aa55aa55
# 7 7 12345678
# 8 8 9ABCDEF0
```

Column `s` is a 32bit hex value which I want to add as the real bit string to the data frame as new column `sbin`.
It should look like this afterwards:

```
df
#   n        s                             sbin
# 1 1 55aa55aa 01010101101010100101010110101010
# 2 2 aa55aa55 10101010010101011010101001010101
# 3 3 12345678 00010010001101000101011001111000
# 4 4 9ABCDEF0 .......
# 5 5 55aa55aa ......
# 6 6 aa55aa55
# 7 7 12345678
# 8 8 9ABCDEF0
```

For conversion I like to use the "hex2bin" function out of "BMS" package.

I tried this

```
lapply(df$s, hex2bin)
# [[1]]
#  [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0

# [[2]]
#  [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

# [[3]]
#  [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0

# .....
```

but did not get the required output.

In the end I would like to access each bit in the data frame rows. So I would like to get 32 vectors with 8 bits each in this example.

Comment: Hmm you mean like `mapply(hex2bin, df$s)` or `do.call(cbind, lapply(df$s, hex2bin))`? Those are matrices, where you can easily access each row ("vector") or bit (cell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
df$sbin <- sapply(df$s, FUN = function(x) { paste(hex2bin(x), collapse = "") })

# n        s                             sbin
# 1 1 55aa55aa 01010101101010100101010110101010
# 2 2 aa55aa55 10101010010101011010101001010101
# 3 3 12345678 00010010001101000101011001111000
# 4 4 9ABCDEF0 10011010101111001101111011110000
# 5 5 55aa55aa 01010101101010100101010110101010
# 6 6 aa55aa55 10101010010101011010101001010101
# 7 7 12345678 00010010001101000101011001111000
# 8 8 9ABCDEF0 10011010101111001101111011110000
```

Comment: Thanks dikesh, thats exactly what i wanted;-))